# Trying to do UI updates in async function

Tags: ios, swift, swiftui

I have an async function that purchases a subscription. It then dismisses the view via the `DismissAction` that was passed to it, sets a `@Published` value to true, and then sets the alternate app icon.

The following code doesn't work properly due to UI updates being called from an async function:

```
func makePurchase(dismiss: DismissAction) async throws {
  let (_, purchaserInfo, _) = try await Purchases.shared.purchasePackage(selectedPackage)
  
  dismiss() // Doesn't like this
  if purchaserInfo.hasPermissions {
    upgradeToUltimate() // Or this
  }
}

struct SubscriptionService {
  function upgradeToUltimate() {
    Auth.shared.user?.isUltimate = true // This is setting a @Published that updates UI elements

    if UIApplication.shared.supportsAlternateIcons,
       UIApplication.shared.alternateIconName == nil {
      UIApplication.shared.setAlternateIconName(Constants.AppIconNames.ultimate) // This stops my dismiss() from happening
    }
  }
}
```

So to fix this I've done the following by adding `@MainActor` to the first function and wrapping the second one in a `DispatchQueue` call. It works, but I'm just wondering if there's a better way to do this:

```
@MainActor
func makePurchase(dismiss: DismissAction) async throws {
  let (_, purchaserInfo, _) = try await Purchases.shared.purchasePackage(selectedPackage)
  
  dismiss()
  if purchaserInfo.hasPermissions {
    SubscriptionService.upgradeToUltimate()
  }
}

struct SubscriptionService {
  static func upgradeToUltimate() {
    DispatchQueue.main.async {
      Auth.shared.user?.isUltimate = true

      if UIApplication.shared.supportsAlternateIcons,
         UIApplication.shared.alternateIconName == nil {
          UIApplication.shared.setAlternateIconName(Constants.AppIconNames.ultimate)
      }
    }
  }
}
```

Answer (score 1):

Interacting with the UI must only be done on the main thread/queue/actor. You've done this correctly.